# .php? Where is insecurity?

Tags: php, security

After successful login user is redirected to menu.php and this is the only file where will do password protected actions (activities).

If user needs to add new company I have link

```
<a href="menu.php?add_new_company" title="">Add new company</a>
```

Below in the file is code

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 'add_new_company') { echo 'Input form' }
```

Have read that this is insecure and it is bad design. However do not understand how someone can hack it. 
Please, advice where there is security problem (if any) (how someone can hack)?

Update

After successful login, token is created and recorded in mysql. In menu.php check if token issset, if yes, connect to mysql, check if exists.
If not isset or does not exist in mysql, redirect to login.

Comment: What happens if I access `menu.php?add_new_company` directly?

Comment: Now i got confident if you have written the login sytem i can exploit that too. Just check if the have logged in every page that only registered user can see. If they are not logged in show 403 forbidden or redirect them to login page. Thats everything for today.

Comment: if access menu.php?add_new_company directly (without login) redirected to login page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `menu.php?action=add_new_company` can be accessed by anyone anywhere, logged in or not. It's your call to actually do session validation on the `menu.php` page.

A part from that, from what you have posted there's nothing really insecure or that can be exploited, as far as the output of that request don't depend on the user input (otherwise we would have XSS).

It's just bad design because that is not a *well-formed* query string. Query strings are supposed to contain a `key=value` list and were not meant to be used that way.

I'd go with something like:

```
<a href="menu.php?action=add_new_company" title="">Add new company</a>
```

and:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'add_new_company') { echo 'Input form' }
```

Comment: @JanDvorak, I think that his / her "add a new company" means to just print the form to add a new *company* (which would actually add the company). Printing a new page is not considered side-effect.

Comment: Where is the answer? Isn't your code really exploitable? How it differs from the users code?

Comment: @silentboy, he asked if it is exploitable, I've answered no (with the defined limitation). If you think is exploitable, prove it. It differs in the sense that it uses `GET` variables as they should, instead of using the query string. Can I ask you a question now? Did you read my answer before down voting?

Comment: @silentboy . Jueecy just describes the best practice of setting querys in urls and how to retrieve values from them. It has nothing to do with the actual login-system.

Comment: Yeah, i have just seen that you have edited the answer with the actual advice i expect from a genius like you. I think you have read the question before answer. As they asked if it not secure, i might say yeah( you say no ). But exploiting means( in my words ) getting access which i do not belong. The user might use this pattern into a sensible application. So, as the question is about security, i would say its insecure. And you arent my enemy. +2 as you have edited your answer decribing the right path. Interested to know your opinion about my thinkingz

Comment: omg, just because it uses the magical POST or GET method, it doesn't mean it's automatically insecure (or hackable). There is NOTHING in the code above that is insecure, hence that the `if` statement will not even pass if it does not equal `add_new_company`, so how the frag do you want to `hack` that .. ?

Comment: @Jueecy yea the (at) seems still broken on safari, it was a response to `silentboy` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, someone can call `menu.php?add_new_company` and can create a new company without password protection? Only the menu is password protected?

This is very insecure because if the user was logged in sometime before and knows the URL, or just guesses it, he can authenticate (again) without password.

Please refer to [OWASP secure coding practices](https://www.owasp.org/images/0/08/OWASP_SCP_Quick_Reference_Guide_v2.pdf), espacially the section *Authentication and Password Management*